# Reading large number of files(20k+) in python memory Error

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to read a large number of files 20k+ from my computer using python but I keep on getting this Memory ERROR(details below). Although I have 16GB of RAM from which 8 GB or more is free all the time and the size of all the files is just 270Mb. I have tried many different solutions like pandas `read_csv()` reading in chunks using `open(file_path).read(100)` and many others but I am unable to read the files. I have to create a corpus of words after reading the files in the list. Below is my code so far. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

collectionPath = r"C:\Users\Asghar Nazir\OneDrive - Higher Education Commission\MSDS\S1\IR\assignment\ACL txt"

listOfFilesInCollection = os.listdir(collectionPath)

def wordList(file):
    list_of_words_from_file =[]
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            list_of_words_from_file.append(word)
    return list_of_words_from_file


list_of_file_word_Lists = {}
file=[]
for file_name in listOfFilesInCollection:
    filePath = collectionPath + "\\" + file_name
    with open(filePath) as f:
        for line in f:
            file.append(line)
    list_of_file_word_Lists[file_name]=wordList(file)
print(list_of_file_word_Lists)
```

The error that I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Asghar
> Nazir/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/IRAssignment1/**init**.py", line
> 25, in 
> list_of_file_word_Lists[file_name]=wordList(file)   File "C:/Users/Asghar
> Nazir/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/IRAssignment1/**init**.py", line
> 14, in wordList
> list_of_words_from_file.append(word) MemoryError

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move the `file=[]` at the beginning of the loop because you're currently adding lines of each new file you open without having first removed the lines of all the previous files.

Then, there're very likely more efficient approaches depending on what you're trying to achieve. If the order of words doesn't matter, then maybe using using a `dict` or a `collections.Counter` instead of a `list` can help to avoid duplication of identical strings. If neither the order nor the frequency of words matter, then maybe using a `set` instead is going to be even better.

Finally, since it's likely you'll find most words in several files, try to store each of them only once in memory. That way, you'll be able to scale way higher than a mere 20k files: there's plenty of space in 16 GiB of RAM.

Keep in mind that Python has lots of fixed overheads and hidden costs: inefficient data structures can cost way more than you would expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have moved the list inside the loop at the beginning now. For 2nd suggestion, I do need a list. I am still getting memory error my program runs for 1 to 1.5 minutes then show the error my files are of size in the range 20Kb to 30Kb max each.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell why your memory problems arise without knowing the content of your files. Maybe it is enough to make your code more efficient. For example: The split()-function can handle multiple lines itself. So you don't need a loop for that. And using list comprehension is always a good idea in python.

The following code should return what you want and I don't see a reason why you should run out of memory using it. Besides that, Arkanosis' hint to the importance of data types is very valid. It depends on what you want to achieve with all those words.

```
from pathlib import Path

def word_list_from_file(path):
    with open(path, 'rt') as f:
        list_words = f.read().split()
    return list_words
    
path_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\Asghar Nazir\OneDrive - Higher Education Commission\MSDS\S1\IR\assignment\ACL txt")
dict_file_content = {
    str(path.name): word_list_from_file(path)
    for path in path_dir.rglob("*.txt")
}
```

P.S.: I'm not sure how the pathlib-module works in windows. But from what I read, this code snippet is platform independent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am still getting memory error my program runs for 1 to 1.5 minutes then show the error my files are of size in the range 20Kb to 30Kb max each. All files are text files

Comment: @Asghar This seems strange to me. Maybe it is related to OneDrive somehow? But I cannot think of a reason why. What happens if you write the content of all files to your local disk? Apart from that the only solution I can think of is to do it in several steps. ` list_paths = list(path_dir.rglob("*.txt"))[0:1000] ... `
On the other hand: A word list of 270 MB is probably not what you want in the end. Maybe you can do your analysis on each file instead of on all of them and then aggregate the results?